# Ionicframework, Trigger alert after state change

Tags: ionic-framework

Afternoon all,

We are a little new to [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), we have managed to add the 'cordovaBarcodeScanner' without any issues and we scan scan qr codes and on success state changes but doesn't trigger alert afterwords.

If anyone can see what we are doing wrong this would help massively.

Thank you.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller("PetIndexCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {

        $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(result) {
                $rootScope.barcoderesults = [{
                  Result: result.text,
                    Format: result.format,
                    Cancelled: result.cancelled
                }];
                $state.go('tab.pet-detail');
                alert(result.text);
            }, function(error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            });
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 6):

So you'd want to start tapping into events from Ui-Router.

```
.controller('RootCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $timeout){


  $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
             function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    $ionicLoading.show();
  });


  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $ionicLoading.hide()
    },2000);
  });

})
```

So in this example, I'm just showing a loader when you change states, then hiding after the state change was successful.

[Simple Demo](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/FjofC)